# Shouldn't the users on codegolf be able to close their questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, code-golf, closed-questions, reputation

Shouldn't the users on codegolf be able to close their question after let's say the question's winners are announced without them having to have some amount of reputation?

Comment: You should ask on meta.codegolf, first as this directly impacts that community.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I thought that the closing your own question was relevant to all the sites? Aren't there the same rules?

Comment: Mind you my answer is going to be *strongly* "No", because it will just caue endless duplicates when later comers want to play.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian the OP is asking for special rules for that particular site.  Ultimately, it should be discussed on that community's meta.

Answer (score 2):

No. The purpose of closing questions is to prevent answers being posted while problems with the question are fixed. If it's a good question, there's no benefit to anyone in preventing everyone from posting answers.

In addition, the last time community feeling on the subject of saying "This person has won: game over" was taken, it was [strongly against](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/542/194).